# Mousemove child div within parent, but stick to sides?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using jQuery `mousemove` to move a child `<div>` within its parent, in order to create an image magnification effect. This is working well (see fiddle) however I want to ensure that the zoomed image can never move further than it's own size. At the moment, when moving the `<div>`, you can see white space on the right and bottom, but I'd like the image to just 'stop' if it reaches this extremity. Is that possible?

[FIDDLE](https://codepen.io/kaleidografik/pen/ZgOPPo)

```js
$('.magnify').each(function() {
  // Vars
  var attr = $(this).attr('data-image-src');

  // Set background image from data attribute
  $(this).css('background-image', 'url(' + attr + ')');

  $(this).on('mousemove touchmove', function(e) {
    // Vars
    var img = $(this).find('img');
    var posX = e.offsetX ? (e.offsetX) : e.pageX - img.offsetLeft;
    var posY = e.offsetY ? (e.offsetY) : e.pageY - img.offsetTop;

    // 
    $(this).css('background-position', (-posX * 2) + "px " + (-posY * 4) + "px");
  });
});
```

```css
#image {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: white;
}

#image .magnify {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: 200%;
  background-color: white;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  opacity: 0;
}

#image:hover .magnify {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="image">
  <img src="https://loremflickr.com/300/150">
  <div class="magnify" data-image-src="https://loremflickr.com/600/300"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: hint: `if (posX > 150) { posX = img.width() / 2; }`

Comment: How could I implement this into the above code?

Comment: like this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZgOZxP

Comment: Thanks for this, but it seems to still have the same problem on the left and right?

Comment: Can you try it now?

Comment: Ah ah! That is working on the right, but problem remains on the bottom (white is shown).

Comment: Looks ok to me, try to refresh the pen

Comment: Nice, yes that has done the trick, thank you! if you'd like to convert this into an answer I'll mark as accepted? Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think you should first convert fixed numbers I put in (150 and 37) those should come out of a calculation

Comment: Yes, how could I go about doing that? We need to detect width/height of #image, is that right? Could you possibly update?

Comment: @GrafiCode - any chance you can help with this last hurdle?